# Python Encoding Error, not unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

How to get rid of the "u" without having other encoding problems ?

```
u"Example Characters : \xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa0"
```

Here what it prints :

```
Example Characters : Ã© Ã
```

Instead of :

```
Example Characters : é à
```

I encounter this problem when using getText() on a BeautifulSoup element. 
(The webpage is in UTF-8)

Comment: `print u"Example Characters : \xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa0".encode("latin-1")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: That is locking the barn after the horse has bolted. Better to not get into this mess in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (wrong decoding of the input).

You most likely passed a Unicode string to `BeautifulSoup()`. **Don't do this**, leave decoding to BeautifulSoup.

For example, if you used `requests`, use `response.content`, not `response.text` to pass the HTML to `BeautifulSoup()`. Otherwise you run the risk of the result being decoded as Latin-1, the default encoding for text responses over HTTP without an explicit character set mentioned in the headers. If you used `urllib2`, *don't* decode first.

BeatifulSoup detects the encoding and decodes for you; it'll use HTML `<meta>` tags if present. UTF-8 should be autodetected correctly. If you know the encoding up front and BeautifulSoup got it wrong anyway, use `from_encoding` to specify the correct encoding:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource, from_encoding='utf8')
```

See the [*Encodings* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) of the BeautifulSoup documentation.

If after all that you are *still* getting Mojibake results then the *web page itself* has produced data with incorrectly encoded values. In that case you can undo the error with:

```
mojibake_string.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

This re-interprets the characters in the correct encoding:

```
>>> u"Example Characters : \xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa0".encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'Example Characters : \xe9 \xe0'
>>> print _
Example Characters : é à
```

There is no need to be concerned about the `u` prefix; that is just a type indicator, to show you have a Unicode value.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Indeed, I used requests.

Answer (score 0):

The string you created unambiguously contains the Unicode characters [U+00C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3/index.htm), [U+00A9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm), and [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm).  Their printed representation is the string you say you don't want.

Apparently you are trying to embed a UTF-8 string.  That's a byte string (`b'...'` in Python 3.x), not a Unicode string (`u'...'`).  To get the string you actually wanted, try

```
"Example Characters : \xc3\xa9 \xc3\xa0".decode('utf-8')
```

which produces a Unicode string containing the actual characters you want.

See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html